# Trailing return type declaration, old-style definition

Tags: c++11

I have a member function prototype in the declaration of class `bar`:

```
auto foo(void) const -> double;
```

and this definition in a source file:

```
double bar::foo(void) const
{
    return 1.0;
}
```

The compilation and link are successful on MSVC2012. But is this mixing the syntax allowed by the standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax makes no difference. The signature in the declaration still matches the one in the definition as they have the same arguments, the same return type, and the same qualifiers.

Comment: (+1) So in this respect it's rather like a `typedef`?

Comment: In a way, yes. If all the types match, it's the same.